# Speeding up Zygote.jl AD

Tags: julia, autodiff

I'm using Julia's `Zygote.jl` package for its auto-diff abilities to calculate option greeks (i.e. the derivatives of the option price relative to the parameters). See below which calculates greeks for a call option using Black Scholes. It takes 40 seconds on my laptop to run. Am I doing something wrong that would cause it to take this much time?

My guess is that the hard part comes when `Zygote` has to differentiate through `Distributions`, but I'm not sure.

```
using Distributions
using Zygote


function bs_call(theta)
    s = theta[1]
    k = theta[2]
    r = theta[3]
    t = theta[4]
    sigma = theta[5]
    vol = sigma * sqrt(t)
    d1 = (log(s / k) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * t) / vol
    d2 = d1 - vol
    n = Normal()
    price = cdf(n, d1) * s - cdf(n, d2) * k * exp(-1.0 * r * t)
    price
end


function main()
    theta = [100, 110, .20, 1.0, .50]
    println(bs_call(theta))
    println(bs_call'(theta))
end


main()
```

Edit: using `SpecialFunctions` (to build a `cdf` function from `erf`) instead of `Distributions` gets me down to 25 seconds. See below:

```
using SpecialFunctions
using Zygote


function cdf(x)
    0.5 * (1 + erf(x / sqrt(2)))
end


function bs_call(theta)
    s = theta[1]
    k = theta[2]
    r = theta[3]
    t = theta[4]
    sigma = theta[5]
    vol = sigma * sqrt(t)
    d1 = (log(s / k) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * t) / vol
    d2 = d1 - vol
    price = cdf(d1) * s - cdf(d2) * k * exp(-1.0 * r * t)
    price
end


function main()
    theta = [100.0, 110.0, .20, 1.0, .50]
    println(bs_call(theta))
    println(bs_call'(theta))
end


main()
```

Comment: Are you measuring the _first_ call? If so, you are measuring mostly compile time and with Zygote 10 or 30 seconds are "normal"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `main` function, you might be executing this in a script. In Julia,you are far better off starting a session (in the REPL, VSCode, Jupyter notebook, or other environment) and running multiple workloads from the same session. As Antonello suggests in a comment, your first call will be dominated by compile time, but the later calls (with the same argument types) simply use the compiled code and can be a completely different experience from the first one.

Some workflow tips can be found in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/workflow-tips/.

Comment: This makes sense. Generally the code above will be embedded in theta learning loops (minimizing pricing discrepancies), so I can see how after compilation the loops will be fine.